# What is the meaning of this sentence? „This is the ante room of ante rooms“

Tags: sentence, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> This is the ante room of ante rooms.

It was used in the document "Inside the Vatican".

Comment: It means that this is the quintessential ante room.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is now clear for me. Josef

Comment: "This is the X of Xes" is an idiom of sorts, meaning this it the epitome of Xes.